# Not sure how to word my Reset action on my android stopwatch

Tags: java, android, reset, stopwatch

I've tried a multitude of ways to solve my problem , but i'm fairly new to coding, so I need help on how to correctly 'Word' the action in my stopwatch that resets the stopwatch. All that it needs to do is somehow reset the current values back to 00:00:00, as it was before the timer was started, but i'm not sure how to go about this...   Here is the section of the XML that i'm struggling with:

```js
resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        return timeInMillies = startTime;
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(timeInMillies = 00:00:00))
        long timeInMillies = 0L;
        long timeSwap = 0L;
        long finalTime = 0L;
```

However, everything else is fine and works like a charm. Here's the entire XML if it can help you out:

```js
package com.jackson.eason.stopwatch;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private Button resetButton;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMillies = 0L;
    long timeSwap = 0L;
    long finalTime = 0L;

    private TextView textTimer;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timeSwap += timeInMillies;
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);

            }
        });

        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        return timeInMillies = startTime;
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(timeInMillies = 00:00:00))
        long timeInMillies = 0L;
        long timeSwap = 0L;
        long finalTime = 0L;



    }
    private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

            int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
            textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're missing an `android` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reset button, there are 2 things you need to change:

1) the textfield.

2) the variables that keep the startTime and timeSwap.

but yet you do not want to change the stage of the app, which I would do it in the following way:

```
   resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textTimer.setText("" + 00 + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", 00) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", 00));
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            timeSwap=0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kaho! I would have never thought of that!